# I killed my projects BD, but I need it for tomorow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, github

I finished few minutes ago my project. I made a commit, after this I wanted to clear DB because there was many testing records. So I ran this in my `DBconsole`:

```
sqlite> delete from users where id;
sqlite> delete from users where id=1;
sqlite> delete from posts where id=1;
sqlite> delete from votes where id=1;
```

After this my project didn't work(((. It returns:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
On every page, even statics!!!!

I need my project to tomorrow. I restored from Git, but error is not disappeared.

My logs see like this:

```
    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-14 04:08:40 +0200
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 2
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."statut" BETWEEN 3 AND 4)
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 2 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."statut" BETWEEN 3 AND 4) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (23.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 2
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."statut" BETWEEN 3 AND 4)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 2
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."statut" BETWEEN 3 AND 4)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."statut" = 2
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."statut" BETWEEN 3 AND 4)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 74ms
```

This is for main page. Help me!! I can give u a git, I need to repair it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deleted all your users with this statement.

```
delete from users where id;
```

So the line in the log

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
```

Won't be able to load user with id 8 because the table is empty. Maybe you need to add back a user crucial for your program to function.

Comment: Maybe, but the /users/new doesn't work(
It return:

        Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-14 04:20:22 +0200
    Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
      Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

And my users have a password with hash, how to create him?

Comment: Are you currently logged in as a user? Clear your brower's cookies and try again.